# What are the partial derivatives of $f(x,y)=x^3-3xy^2$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

What are the partial derivatives of $f(x,y)=x^3-3xy^2$?

I thought $f_x= 3x^2-3y^2$ and $f_y= -6y$ however I need to ensure whether these are correct.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x,y)=x^3-3xy^2$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=3x^2-3y^2\mbox{ (treating }y\mbox{ as constant)}$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=-6xy\mbox{ (treating }x\mbox{ as constant)}$$

Yes, you are correct.